# Regular expression that match string without fixed length

Tags: javascript, regex, alphanumeric

i have a strings like this

```
01084700069811461719010010285322921DA192089940088
01084700088763891719050010BM2120
```

Those strings are datamatrix string, and i have to split strings in this way

```
0108470006981146 17190100 102853229 21DA192089940088

0108470008876389 17190500 10BM2120
```

Each block start with a fixed code and is followed by digits o characters

- 01 + 14 digits
- 17 + 6 digits
- 10 + from 1 to 20 characters
- 21 + from 1 to 20 characters

I try to make this using regular expression, and for the first two blocks i don't have problems because the length is fixed. I have problems with the third (and/or the fourth) block.

I create this regexp

```
/^(01\d{14})(?:(17\d{6}))*(?:(10\w*))*(?:(21\w*))*$/
```

For this string is correct

```
01084700088763891719050010BM2120

Group 1. 0108470008876389 (ok)

Group 2. 17190500 (ok)

Group 3. 10BM2120 (ok)
```

but for the other string

```
01084700069811461719010010285322921DA192089940088
```

the regexp match

```
Group 1. 0108470006981146 (ok)

Group 2. 17190100 (ok)

Group 3. 10285322921DA192089940088 (no)
```

I don't be able to create a regexp that is able to match correctly the third  and the fourth block because have not a fixed length of characters and because is possible that in the third block there is the string "21" that is also the start code of the next block.

It's possibile to create a regular expression that match correctly all the parts of the string.

Thanks to all

Comment: Try [`^(01\d{14})(17\d{6})?(10\w{1,20})?(21\w{1,20})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/0p9Uz5/1) if these blocks are consecutive and `b`, `c`, or `d` can be optional.

Comment: The 3rd and the 4th block start with "10" and "21", and in regular expression is matched by *(?:(10\w*))*(?:(21\w*))* part.
The 3rd block start with "10" and can contains the number 21 inside, but 21 is also the start code for the 4th block. Both block don't have a fixed length

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/0p9Uz5/1. Is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: Nice shot. Seem to be worked well! :D Thanks, you saved my day

Comment: Why is `0108470008876389 17190500 10BM 2120` not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(01\d{14})(17\d{6})?(10\w{1,20})?(21\w{1,20})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0p9Uz5/1)

Note that you do not have to wrap the capturing groups with non-capturing ones if you plan to quantify them, you may quantify the capturing groups directly.

Also, to make a group optional, it is enough to use `?` quantifier, as `*` matches 0 or more occurrences.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(01\d{14})` - Group 1: `01` and 24 digits
- `(17\d{6})?` - Group 2 (optional): `17` and 6 digits
- `(10\w{1,20})?` - Group 3 (optional): `10` and 1 to 20 word chars
- `(21\w{1,20})?` - Group 4 (optional): `21` and 1 to 20 word chars
- `$` - end of string.

Note that to match only alphanumeric chars, you need to replace `\w` with `[^\W_]` since `\w` also matches `_`.

Comment: I love regexp but are also very dangerous :D. Do you have a resource to master regexp in this way?

Comment: @AngelPoyel This kind of regex knowledge is not advanced, you may learn this at http://regexone.com. Subtracting `_` from `\w` is a bit more "hidden", you may learn this at SO.

Answer (score 0):

var inputValue = **"01084700088763891719050010BM2120"**;

var regexpr = /(01\d{14})(17\d{6})(10[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})(21[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})/;

inputValue.replace(regexpr, "$1  $2  $3  $4");

The output will be :

> "0108470008876389  17190500  10BM  2120"

var inputValue = **"01084700069811461719010010285322921DA192089940088"**;

var regexpr = /(01\d{14})(17\d{6})(10[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})(21[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})/;

inputValue.replace(regexpr, "$1  $2  $3  $4");

The output will be :

> "0108470006981146  17190100  102853229  21DA192089940088"